# How to: ZFS dataset per user

Tags: linux, zfs, nas

My roommates and I are going to build a NAS server at home with ZFS but each of us want to have our own separated space.

Is it possible to create several different datasets and assign each one to a user so data can only be accessible by the owner?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. I suggest you try using create time permissions on the base dataset. This is accomplished by using the `-c` option to `zfs allow` but first you would allow the users to create new datasets. For example, you could first have a base dataset `mypool/base` and to this base dataset you allow create permission locally using `allow -l -u <user> <permission>[,<permission>...] mypool/base`. This would allow user1 to create their own dataset `mypool/base/<user1data>` and likewise for other users but it doesn't allow them to destroy or mount other users' datasets.

Now, you can use the `zfs allow -c` option to allow broader permissions on the descendant datasets that will be sufficient for you once you create you own dataset.

From the man pages:

`zfs allow -c perm|@setname[,...] filesystem|volume Sets "create time" permissions. These permissions are granted (locally) to the creator of any newly-created descendent file system.`

So, by providing broader create time permissions each user could have the full gamut of permissions that will apply only to the datasets that *they* have created. Try it out with some bogus datasets just to get a sense of how it works.

Alternatively, users must own the mountpoint of the dataset that they are trying to mount so you could preconfigure the dataset mountpoints to be on a directory owned by the corresponding user.

Comment: Nice alternative for perms on mountpoints.  Been using that for years on other apps as well.